# Brackets around multiple lines

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am trying to put big rounded brackets around some text that contains math formulas:

```
Jede Teilfolge hat entweder unendliche viele Elemente von $\left( g_{2n}\right)$ oder $\left( g_{2n+1}\right)$.\todo{Add big bracket}
\[\left. {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{g_ + } = \lim {a_n} = \lim {g_{2n}} = g}\\
{{g_ + } = \lim {b_n} = \lim {g_{2n}} = g}
\end{array}} \right\}{g_ + } = {g_ - } \Rightarrow \lim {g_n} = g = {g_ - } = {g_ + } = \frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2}\]
```

The result that I am looking for is something along these lines:

```
( First Line  )
( Second Line )
( Third Line  )
```

All of the solutions that I have found force me to go into mathmode, clashing with the formulas, or they use tikz in an enumerated list, which I haven't been able to adapt to my situation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Looks like I didn't explain myself too well. Here something I sketched up, hope this explains it better:
[image: quickMockup]

Of course the brackets should be as tall as the text, and not go over like in my sketch

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing: The code you've posted features a single right-hand-side curly brace, yet you also state that you want large "rounded brackets" (same as parentheses?) on both sides of the multiline expression. Please clarify.

Comment: What I am trying to do is wrap the above code inside of parenthesis, so to enclose the whole thing, like you would do with \left( and \right) when in mathmode

Comment: What I do not understand is that you mention using parentheses *as* in math mode, but all  your formulae are maths. So where is the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `rcases` or `drcases` environment from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Jede Teilfolge hat entweder unendliche viele Elemente von $(g_{2n})$ oder
$(g_{2n+1})$.
\[
\begin{drcases}
g_+ = \lim a_n = \lim g_{2n} = g\\
g_+ = \lim b_n = \lim g_{2n} = g
\end{drcases}
g_+ = g_- \Rightarrow \lim g_n = g = g_- = g_+ = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that you're using too many braces; also there's no need to have `\left` or `\right` before all delimiters: it's even discouraged, as it affects spacing.

Usually I also recommend to always have braces around subscripts and superscripts, even if they are only one token, but an experienced user knows when to sin against this “rule”.

[image]

I wouldn't use brackets around the whole construction, but the document is yours; here is how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\[
\sbox{\tempbox}{%
  $\displaystyle
    \begin{drcases}
    g_+ = \lim {a_n} = \lim g_{2n} = g\\
    g_+ = \lim {b_n} = \lim g_{2n} = g
    \end{drcases} 
    g_+ = g_- \Rightarrow \lim g_n = g = g_- = g_+ = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}
  $%
}
\begin{pmatrix}
\,\parbox[b]{\wd\tempbox}{
  Jede Teilfolge hat entweder unendliche viele Elemente von
  $(g_{2n})$ oder $(g_{2n+1})$.
}\hfill\, % left alignment
\\[\abovedisplayskip]
\,\usebox{\tempbox}\,
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I should have used the notation you used in your code, but I haven't really had the time to go back and change all my code to the correct one. The one I posted above was generated ages ago using MathType, since I didn't know a better way!