# Curly brackets spanning multiple lines (no math env)

Tags: brackets

For language learning purposes I would like to use curly brackets with an selection of objects (multiple lines of text, no math environment like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186448/brackets-around-multiple-lines)).

[image: Result needed]

But the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{empheq}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium Plus}


\begin{document}

I want to buy
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace,right=\empheqrbrace]{align*}
    tomatoes \\
    onions \\
    cucumbers
\end{empheq}
in the market.

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Wrong result]

In addition the words within the brackets should be left aligned.

Comment: To expand on David's answer: you need an alignment environment that aligns to the left (`align*` alternates between right and left alignment). You also need something to switch to text mode, like `\text{tomatoes}`. David used a `tabular` environment to perform both of these functions.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, Dan. I use a math environment but within that I switch to a text environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,verbose]{geometry}

\begin{document}

I want to buy
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    tomatoes \\
    onions \\
    cucumbers
\end{tabular}
\right\}$
in the market.

\end{document}
```