# Curly brackets spanning multiple lines (no math env) | Only 1 curly bracket, at 1 side

Tags: tables

Adapted from the question:

- [Curly brackets spanning multiple lines (no math env)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212831/curly-brackets-spanning-multiple-lines-no-math-env)

Inside a tabular environment (non-math context), how to have **only 1 curly bracket** (e.g. only the left one) spanning multiple lines of text, please?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

I don't want the right curly bracket,
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{c}
list item 1 \\
list item 2 \\
list item 3
\end{tabular}
\right\}$
only the left one please.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `\right\}` to `\right.`. (The "`.`" immediately after `\right` stands for "nothing here".)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

I'm getting a left-hand curly brace
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
list item 1 \\
list item 2 \\
list item 3
\end{tabular}
\right.$
and none on the right.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really nice. I posted a follow-up question (for items within an Itemize environment) at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304741/how-to-have-curly-bracket-spanning-items-of-itemize, if interested.