# How to have curly bracket spanning items of Itemize

Tags: itemize, brackets

We already know how to have a curly bracket spanning multiple non-math lines of text:

- Cf. [Curly brackets spanning multiple lines (no math env) | Only 1 curly bracket, at 1 side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304725/curly-brackets-spanning-multiple-lines-no-math-env-only-1-curly-bracket-at)

What I wonder now is: how to do the same with:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{itemize}
```

How to have a curly bracket spanning over such **Items**, within an **Itemize**-environment?

Comment: There is an example in [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1559/5764)

Comment: @Werner, Thanks. Can you do it for a left-hand curly brace? Cf. the problem in the answer which I provided below.

Comment: What is the desired output if there is a page break between the items?

Comment: @Aditya On the purposes which I base myself, I think the most legible would be to break such a large brace into 2 smaller braces, one for each page. But, for other purposes it might be better to retain 1 big brace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not too hard to adapt the answer you already found :)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{p{.8\textwidth}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Second line 
\item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
\item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\right.$
\end{document}
```

The spacing could use some work but I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Following Werner's comment, which links to:

- [User Cmhuges' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277825/67761) to the question [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)

I end up with the following, which (when one would like a left-curly brace) however results in the left brace being oriented falsely (it should be flipped horizontally).

A correct way for the right curly brace can be found in the mentioned [User Cmhuges' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277825/67761).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newtcolorbox{leftbrace}{%
    enhanced jigsaw, 
    breakable, % allow page breaks
    frame hidden, % hide the default frame
    overlay={%
        \draw [
            decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},
            decorate,
            ultra thick,
        ]
        % right line
        (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
    },
    % paragraph skips obeyed within tcolorbox
    parbox=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbrace}
\begin{itemize}
\item Second line 
\item Third line, which is quite long and seemingly tedious in the extreme
\item Fourth line, which isn't as long as the third 
\end{itemize}
\end{leftbrace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to do it the same way but the curly brace is horizontally flipped?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation points to comment back to you @Anas A. Ibrahim, but to have a horizontal brace pointing downward you would change the line under the "`%right line`" comment to: `(frame.south west)--(frame.south east)`. If you want the horizontal brace to point upward, change that same line to: `(frame.north west)--(frame.north east)`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Christina Cole's solution, another way to "flip" the brace is to use the `mirror` option, i.e., replace  `decoration={brace, amplitude=0.5em}` with `decoration={brace, amplitude=0.5em, mirror}`.

source: [How can I flip the direction of curly braces in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/how-can-i-flip-the-direction-of-curly-braces-in-tikz)

Comment: I guess your answer is related to the answer of O0123. Could you please mention that in your text so that it makes sense (as the content of your answer by itself cannot be used).

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to mention what I am responding to.  (I am new to StackExchange, so unfortunately, I couldn't comment directly on the post.)