# Creating a list inside a bracket

Tags: lists, brackets

I would like to know how I can create a bracket around a list, which looks like the picture below:

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at `tcolorbox` package.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304741/134144, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384367/134144

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: How should the list bracket be managed around a page break?

Answer (score 1):

I started using only `\vbox`, etc... but so I am told this is scary, so I tried my best to use LaTeX boxes which however all force quitting vertical mode which induces complications for vertical spacing. Anyway,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
XXXX

\noindent\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\hrule width 10pt
  \noindent
  \mbox{\vrule
    \hspace{8pt}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-0.4pt-8pt\relax}

    \vspace{4pt}

    This is my list, you may want to configure it using package
    enumitem for example to modify the label indent. The various
    vspace allow to customize vertical spacing.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \vspace{6pt}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hrule width 10pt
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
}

XXXX

\end{document}
```

[image]