# Brackets next to subsections

Tags: align, itemize, minipage, brackets

I created a long list using itemize, minipages and sections/subsections...

Now, I would like to replace the subsection text by a bracket that is placed next to the equations of each subsection. See image:

[image]

Is that possible? The brackets *can* be aligned, but they don't have to.

**CODE:**

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section{A List}
\subsection{$O(\epsilon^0)$}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Tilde{\pi}_{0}$
    \item $\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}$
\end{itemize}
\subsection{$O(\epsilon^1$)}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{0,\mathrm{m}}$
    \item $\frac{\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}(\Bar{p}w_{1})$
    \item $\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}w_{1}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}\Bar{\Theta}$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\nabla_{\mathrm{m}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_{0,\mathrm{m}}$
    \item $\frac{\alpha_{\mathrm{w}}}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{\mathrm{z}}(\Bar{p}w_{1})$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304741) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559) answer your question?