# using latex for depicting grammar of file format

Tags: diagrams

I came across the a paper where the STL file format was depicted in the following way.

[image: STL file format]

I would very much be interested in using something similar to this but I have no clue how to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. By "use", do you mean read an STL file (e.g., into Asymptote, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282106/render-stl-files-in-asymptote), or producing one given a structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual solution using a tabular surrounded by curly braces (based on [Curly brackets spanning multiple lines (no math env)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212831/curly-brackets-spanning-multiple-lines-no-math-env)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{solid} \textit{name}\\
$\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \textbf{facet normal} $n_i n_j n_k$ \\
    \hspace{1em}\textbf{outer loop} \\
    \hspace{2em}\textbf{vertex} $v1_x\ v1_y\ v1_z$\\
    \hspace{2em}\textbf{vertex} $v2_x\ v2_y\ v2_z$\\
    \hspace{2em}\textbf{vertex} $v3_x\ v3_y\ v3_z$\\
    \hspace{1em}\textbf{endloop}\\
    \textbf{endfacet}
\end{tabular}
\right\}^+$\\
\textbf{endsolid} \textit{name}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd define an environment that builds a single block with a `tabular` and the inner part with a nested `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{stl}{t+mm}
 {% #1 = optional +, #2 = key, #3 = name
  \renewcommand{\>}{\quad\ignorespaces} % use \> to `advance'
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \stlkey{#2} \textit{#3} \\
  $\left\lbrace\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}\right\rbrace\IfBooleanT{#1}{^+}$ \\
  \stlkey{end#2} \textit{#3}
  \end{tabular}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\stlkey}{m}{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{stl}+{solid}{name}
  \stlkey{facet normal} $n_i n_j n_k$ \\
  \> \stlkey{outer loop} \\
  \>\> \stlkey{vertex} $v1_x\ v1_y\ v1_z$\\
  \>\> \stlkey{vertex} $v2_x\ v2_y\ v2_z$\\
  \>\> \stlkey{vertex} $v3_x\ v3_y\ v3_z$\\
  \> \stlkey{endloop}\\
  \stlkey{endfacet}
\end{stl}

\end{document}
```

You'll need `\usepackage{xparse}` if running LaTeX released prior to 2020-10-01.

The superscript + is only added if you specify it as indicated in the code above. With `\begin{stl}{solid}{name}` the superscript + will not be printed.

The `\>` command is slightly abused, but it seems an easy way to indent the code as wished.

[image]